# Turning single element lists, including NULL, to vector more efficiently

Tags: r

So, I have a list like this, and want to convert to a vector where null lists are replaced by NA. All entries in list always have one element at most (thanks to MongoDB, which only returns nested elements as list).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this rather than a loop (apply family)?

```
dput(l)
list(structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), structure(list(
    postcode = "27612"), .Names = "postcode"), structure(list(
    postcode = "30127"), .Names = "postcode"), structure(list(
    postcode = "35173"), .Names = "postcode"), structure(list(
    postcode = "30047"), .Names = "postcode"), structure(list(
    postcode = "87571"), .Names = "postcode"))
sapply(l, function(x) if (length(x)) unlist(x$postcode) else NA)
[1] NA      "27612" "30127" "35173" "30047" "87571"
```

The output is exactly what I want, but fear on a very large data set, this will be slow. Hoping there is a faster way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do:

```
ll[!lengths(ll)] <- NA
unlist(ll, use.names=FALSE)
```

`[<-` doesn't deep copy the entire list. You can check this by looking at the *address* before and after the operation.

Comment: Very nice....in the case I am dealing with, this postcode is a named field of another list. So, looks like I will have to loop to extract this field first from all elements, and then run this. Perhaps loop is the best I can do.

Comment: This is so much faster than my suggestion, mainly because `lengths` is much faster than `sapply(l, length)`

Comment: @Gopala, not sure.. perhaps worth asking a Q. Perhaps someone else has a way of handling it..

Comment: I just posted a new question with the fuller data and problem. Hope to resolve it as I am running into performance and class coersion challenges.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be faster to preallocate a vector of NAs and then fill in the data

```
x2 <- rep(NA, length(l))
x2[sapply(l,length) == 1] <- unlist(l)
```

However, at least with this sized dataset, it seems to be almost exactly as fast as your approach.

```
library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(
  sapply(l, function(x) if (length(x)) unlist(x$postcode) else NA), 
  {
    x2 <- rep(NA, length(l))
    x2[sapply(l,length) == 1] <- unlist(l)
  }
)
Unit: microseconds
                                                                         expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
   sapply(l, function(x) if (length(x)) unlist(x$postcode) else NA) 22.325 24.012 34.61623 25.056 44.2935 111.639   100
 {x2 <- rep(NA, length(l)) x2[sapply(l, length) == 1] <- unlist(l)} 22.306 24.485 31.44310 25.478 34.5840  90.339   100
```